# Which container should I use?

Tags: haskell

I'm new to haskell, and so I'm trying to recreate the following C++ code in haskell.

```
int main() {
    class MyClass {
        public:
        int a;
        std::string s;
        float f;
    };
    std::vector <MyClass> v;
    LoadSerialized(&v); // don't need haskell equivalent; just reads a bunch of MyClass's and pushes them back onto v
}
```

Now, I've looked at the various containers in haskell that might work as the std::vector here: there's list, unboxed vector, boxed vector, and some weird usage of foreign pointers like the following:

```
data Table = Table { floats :: ForeignPtr CFloat
                   , ints   :: ForeignPtr Int    }

newTable :: IO Table
newTable = do
    fp <- S.mallocByteString (floatSize * sizeOf (undefined :: CFloat))
    ip <- S.mallocByteString (intSize   * sizeOf (undefined :: Int   ))
    withForeignPtr fp $ \p ->
        forM_ [0..floatSize-1] $ \n ->
            pokeElemOff p n pi
    withForeignPtr ip $ \p ->
        forM_ [0..intSize-1]   $ \n ->
            pokeElemOff p n n
    return (Table fp ip)
```

Now, I could implement the C++ code in the way I think is best--being a haskell newbie. Or I could ask people more experienced with the language what the best way is, because to me it looks like there's some nuance going on here that I'm missing. Simply, I want to push a structure containing many datatypes into a haskell container, and I don't care about the order. If it helps, I'm going to read serialized data into the container as you can see with `LoadSerialized`.

I'm not mixing in C++ code.

(Edit: is it stackoverflow policy to allow censorship of questions through editing (not minor)? It does say "always respect the original author.")

Comment: n.b. It's within the intent of the system that editors remove unnecessary rudeness from questions, yes. StackOverflow is a place for people to ask and answer programming questions, it is not a place for bad tempered arguments to break out.

Comment: Rudeness? How was that rude? That was explaining exactly why I unnecessarily rewrote the question posted right before this one.

Comment: ehird, you're taking more out that than I put in to it (the tone was meant to be matter-of-fact), but alright I'm overruled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>If you are writing the whole program in Haskell,</s> Just use a list unless you have a good reason not to. (If you do have a good reason not to, please say what it is and we can help you choose a more appropriate data structure. e.g. random access to a specific list element is O(n) rather than the O(1) of a C++ vector, and updating values in a data structure is different in Haskell.)

<s>If you are mixing Haskell and C++ in the same program, and you need help calling C++ from Haskell, please say.</s>

- Use lists by default. List operations such as `map`, `foldr` and `filter` can be fused together by the compiler, resulting in more efficient code than you would typically get using a C++ vector.
- Use an array of some sort if you find yourself needing to lookup an element by index, or wanting to mutate an element at a specific index. See [Data.Array](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/array-0.4.0.0/Data-Array.html), [Data.Array.IO](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/array-0.4.0.0/Data-Array-IO.html), and [Data.Array.ST](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/array-0.4.0.0/Data-Array-ST.html).
- Use a sequence if you find yourself needing to insert new elements in the middle of the data structure, or at both ends of the structure. See [Data.Sequence](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers-0.4.2.1/Data-Sequence.html).

Comment: Not mixing in C++. The reason I thought list might be a bad idea here is that there are apparently performance issues. Moreover, I thought there may be a parallel with C++ in that you just don't use certain containers for certain problems: eg., std::list should rarely be used in place of std::vector even though it works. Apparently, the haskell vector containers are more perfomant than list for this problem in haskell? But why recommend them?

Comment: Hadn't even heard of Data.Array or Sequence. Wish there was a complexity table for all the haskell data structures. One last thing, what should I use Data.Vector for? And I assume the foreign pointer method should only be used when mixing C++ code?

Comment: Yeah, I wrote that in response to your edit. What is Data.Vector used for, is it correct that the foreign pointer method should only be used when mixing C++ code? (This info needs to be added to the haskell wiki)

Comment: @user175492: Use `Data.Array` if you need multiple dimensions. For single-dimensional arrays, `Data.Vector` is superior in almost every way. In particular, it has a much nicer interface.

Comment: @hammar: Ahhh, so I should use Data.Vector for this problem then because I'm essentially storing pointers to a structure, right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Data.Vector, it doesn't seem to come with GHC. Foreign pointers are primarily for interfacing with C/C++/etc code, although they are also useful when you need to directly access memory (e.g. they are used to implement `ByteString`s).

Comment: @dave4420: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Serialisation_and_compression_with_Data_Binary this led me to believe that the foreign pointer method was faster than others. Even when it's not necessary to mix with C++ code.

Comment: @user175492: Low-level code like that is a last resort in Haskell for those cases where you really need to squeeze out every last drop of performance. In most cases, the high-level interfaces are fast enough while being _much_ simpler to use.

Comment: @hammar: you're referring to the foreign pointer method or Data.Vector? Should I use Data.Vector to store a bunch of the following `data GUIColumn  = GUICol { colNumber    :: Int,
                           colCells     :: [Panel ()],
                           colButton    :: Button () }`?

Comment: @user175492: using foreign pointers (or equivalently, Data.Vector.Unboxed) is more *space-efficient* than other methods, but may or may not be faster depending on which operations you use.  It's also less convenient because you need to define a Storable instance (or Unbox for Data.Vector.Unboxed).

Comment: Okay, so Vector.Unboxed and foreign pointers are a pain to use for this, but they're faster in some cases. So, unless the performance is needed, stick with dave4420's original suggestions? (Hopefully someone knowledgeable about this can add the info to the haskell wiki and maybe start a complexity table.)

Comment: @user175492: I was referring to foreign pointers (which `Data.Vector` is implemented on top of, if I'm not mistaken). If your GUI only has a handful of columns, I'd probably use lists, simply because they're the easiest to work with. You can easily change to some other data structure later on if necessary. This whole thing smells like premature optimization to me.

Comment: @hammar: I'm just looking for the intuition about which containers to use for what problem. Like it's a bad idea to use C++ lists for storing characters and using the list as a string, and even though you can. Maybe that isn't analogous though. I was just using that GUI column as an example: I'm looking to store a few thousand objects(?) similar to the column type in a container. I'm so confused.

Comment: It's not really algorithmic complexity that dictates which container you should use, but what you'll be using it _for._  Use vectors when you won't be changing values in the container after it's constructed, or when all the containers will have the same size.  Use lists when you'll only be adding elements to one end or the other, or when you want something simple and straightforward.  Use `Data.Sequence` when you'll be adding, modifying, or removing elements at the ends, in the middle.

Comment: (Use mutable arrays or `ForeignPtr` when you need constant-time reads _and writes_ in the middle of the container, and you don't care about how complicated the code will be.)

Comment: @dave4420 `Data.Vector` is pretty much a more efficient version of `Data.Array` with an API that isn't horrible. I'd recommend it over `arrays` any day even if it doesn't come with GHC.